# I am not able to get dump file for crash

Tags: windows, visual-c++, crash

I am getting crash when I stop my server. But I could not see any dump file for this crash. Why dump file is not getting created. If possible could any one let me know where dump file will be created.

Thanks
Haranadh

Answer (score 2):

Intall [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx), before stop your server execute at cmd line:

"C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\adplus" -pn process-name.exe -hang -o path-of-output-files

and the dump file is created for you.

Answer (score 0):

First off: What "server" are you running? Host OS?

Comment: The server is apache server which is coded in C++, part of my project.